# Can you run a simulink model on the unix command line?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I've developed a head tracking simulink model and am wondering if its possible to somehow run this on a unix based os without any window manager? Simply from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start matlab from a unix prompt without the desktop

% matlab -nodesktop

Then you can simulate the model by just loading it,

```
>> load_systm('myModel');
>> sim('myModel');
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this required MATLAB to be installed along with all the necessary toolboxes. I've heard it mentioned that MATLAB can compile/translate to C code, would this work to avoid needing to have MATLAB installed on the deployment machine?

Comment: Yes, if you have Simulink Coder, you can generate C code from your Simulink model, and run that without having MATLAB installed on your machine.  The only restriction is that you would have to use a fixed-step solver.  To use a variable-step solver using rsim, you would need  to check out a Simulink license when you run the executable.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use matlab -r "[matlab statements]" to run your codes?